# Create Map from records of 2 List

Tags: apex, custom-object, map, list

I need to create map from 2 lists. One list ids and another list<custom_object__c> objects. But i dont get how to do it? id list is not id from custom_object__c. With on list it easy, but how to do it with 2 lists?

Id  custom_object__c is connected via contact class with user and id is user id. I am using another method which give me user id with custom_object__c. I am using that fucntion in many other places, so i dont want change it or create another one. And now i want get a map to associate  user id and that custom_object__c.

So one list must be key and another value.

```
map<Id,custom_object__c>MyMap = new map<Id,custom_object__c>(objects);
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). We need some more information: How does a specific `Id` map to a specific `Custom_Object__c`? In other words, what is their connection so that you know which `Custom_Object__c` goes with which `Id`? | This seems like it could be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - so please also tell us *why* you want to map your `Id`s to your `Custom_Object__c`s.

Comment: @Moonpie added but i dont know what it changed. Or its impossible to convert 2 lists into map without that?

Comment: You could take two lists, put them in a loop and easily map one to the other. However, if the two lists are not in the correct order to match up in the map, you will end up with an unhelpful map. So knowing *how* they match can help someone make a helpful suggestion. HOWEVER, the info you added is helpful. Are you saying that the `Id`s in the one list, are User Ids that are also in a field on the `Custom_Object__c`? If so, you don't need to use the `Id` List to create the map.

Comment: @Moonpie  there are no user id field  in Custom_object__c, its a little longer chain to get id.Also i dont understand how to  put 2 lists in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming

- `idList` is your List of `Id`s *in the known correct order*
- `idList` contains at least 1 member
- `customList` is your List of `Custom_Object__c` *in the known correct order **that maps correctly in that order to your `Id`s***
- The two lists are the same length

```
Map<Id, Custom_Object__c> MyMap = new Map<Id, Custom_Object__c>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < idList.size(); i++) {
   MyMap.put(idList[i], customList[i]);
}
```

You could add some validation prior to the `for` loop that verifies that the List sizes match.

*You can temporarily check your results with something like this...*

```
for (Id id : MyMap.keySet()) {
    System.debug('Id: ' + id + ' || Custom Object: ' + MyMap.get(id));
}
```

*...but don't leave that in your code.*

---

On the surface I do not think it is advisable to map two Lists together after both Lists have been separately and independently filled - especially when there is no direct connection between members of each List. If both Lists are not in the *exact* order that you expect, then you will get unexpected results when using the Map.

If there is a way to, I would suggest instead that you create this Map when you create one or both Lists. Or better yet, skip creating one or both Lists and instead create a Map directly.

*(I still think this might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).)*

---

**UPDATE**

From info gleaned from this Q&A ( [Comparing Apex Loops and why Iterators are dramatically slower than for loops?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/344741/81648) ), a more optimal answer might be:

```
for (Integer i = 0, size = idList.size(); i < size; i++) {
   MyMap.put(idList[i], customList[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i was too fixated on for each. List in right order. Method was created specially to save right order.